Linux deb package download with dependencies
I know that the apt command also downloads dependencies of dependencies.
Is there a way to make it work like this, but only download without installing?
Below are the commands I tried.
apt-cache depends libpango1.0-dev | grep "Depends" | awk '{print $2}' |xargs apt-get download
How can I get the dependencies and target packages and download them?
<12-02 edit>
How to download package not install it with apt-get command?
I run command  sudo apt reinstall --download-only libpango1.0-dev
And Error is show like picture.
Above link is just install only pacakage. not include dependincies.

Thanks.

TL;DR is to use the --download-only flag, but...

You can find more detailed answers at this related question: How to download package not install it with apt-get command?. If you believe your question is different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
